# Unable to build an Ionic 3 app for browser. Error: DeepLinkConfigToken

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, browser, ionic3

I've tried build my app for browser with

```
ionic cordova build browser --prod
```

but it throws this error: The RegExp to find the DeepLinkConfigToken did not return valid data

I'm using Angular 4.4.6. I read about downgrading Angular version to 4.1 solves the problem. But I tried it and it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

These are my dependencies:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~4.4.6",
        "@angular/common": "~4.4.6",
        "@angular/compiler": "~4.4.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.4.6",
        "@angular/core": "~4.4.6",
        "@angular/forms": "~4.4.6",
        "@angular/http": "~4.4.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.4.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.4.6",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "~4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "~4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/facebook": "~4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/file": "~4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "~4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/geolocation": "~4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/google-plus": "~4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.7.0",
        "@ionic/storage": "~2.1.3",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "~7.2.2",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "~2.0.1",
        "cordova-android": "~6.4.0",
        "cordova-browser": "~4.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "~4.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "~1.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "~1.1.7",
        "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "~1.9.1",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "~6.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "~1.7.1",
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "~4.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "~5.2.3",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "~2.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "~1.3.3",
        "ionic-angular": "~3.9.2",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "~3.0.0",
        "query-string": "~4.3.4",
        "rxjs": "~5.5.10",
        "sw-toolbox": "~3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
        "typescript": "^2.8.1"
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it updating the package @ionic/app-scripts to 3.8.0 (the latest version at the time) and adding this line to index.html before to the line where main.js is imported

```
<script src="build/vendor.js"></script>
```

I updated all the packages too, but I think app-script update is enough.